# how to take the elements of one form tag into another form tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have 2 form tags . In form1 tag i have a list of checkboxes in it. In form 2 tag i have a href link . When i click the link i want to get the checkboxes of first form tag and process the action of second form tag.

eg:

1st form tag

```
<form action="">
    <!-- checkboxes list -->
</form>
```

2nd form tag

```
<form action="">
    <!-- href -->
</form>


  I have tried the following  code
 form1 
  <form action="abc.pl" id="sel">
  <input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="Milk"> Milk<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="Butter" checked> Butter<br>
  </form>
 form 2
<form id="myform" action="xyz.pl" method="POST">
 <a href="#" id="mylink"> submit </a>
</form>

javascript code is
<script>
   window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById('mylink').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementsById('sel').submit();
    return false;
    };
   };
```

I want to get the checkboxes list of form 1 and process form 2 action. Please help me on how to achieve this.

Comment: Are these forms on the same page?

Comment: @geoff yes they are on the same page :)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @TarunPai i have tried the above code . i dont know wat to give in href so i gave # . i want to run xyz.pl after clicking the link with the checkboxes of first form

Comment: @user3095218, have you tried to change the `action` attribute of form 1 to 'xyz.pl'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for

```
<form action="abc.pl" id="sel">
  <input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="Milk"> Milk<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="Butter" checked> Butter<br>
  </form>
 form 2
<form id="myform" action="xyz.pl" method="POST">
 <a href="#" id="mylink"> submit </a>
</form>

javascript code is
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById('mylink').onclick = function () {
            document.getElementById("sel").action = document.getElementById("myform").getAttribute("action");
            document.getElementById('sel').submit();
            return false;
        };
    };
</script>
```

Comment: akhil Thank u This is what i wanted